# jQuery.on() for children with no particular selector

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I have HTML structure like this:

```html
<div class="parent">

    <div class="child">
        <div class="something">...</div>
    </div>

    <div class="child">
        <div class="something-else">...</div>
    </div>

    <div class="child">
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

I catch events (like `click`) on `.child` elements like this:

```js
$('.parent').on('click', '.child', function() { ... });
```

However, I would like to get rid of explicit class specification and base on the fact of direct ancestry itself.
I want to write the code which would not require any particular classes for children elements. Closest thing to this is:

```js
$('.parent').on('click', '*', function() { ... });
```

But obviously such handler will spread on deeper descendants (`.something`, `.something-else` etc.), not only on the first level.

Is there a way to acheive what I look for, being it using something instead of `*` or some other way?

P.S. I don't want to use direct binding - `$('.parent').children().click(function() {...});` - as it is slower and will not work in case of children being dynamically added.

Comment: Use: `$('.parent').on('click', '> *', function() { ... });`

Comment: @JoshCrozier, this is basically the same as `$('.parent').children().click(...)`.

Comment: No, that isn't the same. View this example demonstrating it -> https://jsfiddle.net/sLnjeom0/ - that appears to be what you want, right?

Comment: @JoshCrozier, looks like you've slightly edited your comment. Originally it was `$('.parent > *').on('click', function() {})`, not `$('.parent').on('click', '> *', function() {})`, as it is now. At this form it is exactly what I want, I have already checked it myself. If you post it as an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector sought for is `> *`:

```js
$('.parent').on('click', '> *', function() { ... });
```

(The actual solution was suggested by Josh Crozier in the comments, I just reposted it as an answer.)